# Double Pendulum RK4

Tags: python, simulation, ode, differential-equations, runge-kutta

I am trying to implement the classical RK4 algorithm to solve the system of differential equations which govern the equations of motion. However, I am having several problems for a while. The equations of motion can be written as below:

[image]

Since this is a system of first order differential equations, we are ready to use RK4 to solve it.
However, **I am really lost in regards to writing the system above in python code.**

There is a related question here: [System of second order ODEs Runge Kutta 4th order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64962719/system-of-second-order-odes-runge-kutta-4th-order) which writes the system of ODES for a different physical system into Python code and also uses RK4 to solve it. However, I have not been able to use that to make my own code work. There is another question [I want to have the pendulum blob in my double pendulum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65224923/i-want-to-have-the-pendulum-blob-in-my-double-pendulum) which is closer to what I want, but it does not take care of the process by using arrays, but rather by writing several equations instead.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def RK4(t, y, h, f):  
    
    #Runge Kutta standard calculations
    k1 = f(t, y)
    k2 = f(t + h/2, y + h/2 * k1)
    k3 = f(t + h/2, y + h/2 * k2)
    k4 = f(t + h, y + h * k3)    

    return 1/6*(k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) 

    
def RHS(t, y):
    
    ################################
    #Critical physical Parameters
    g = 9.8
    l1 = 1
    l2 = 1
    m1 = 1
    m2 = 1
    w1 = w2 = 0
    theta_1 = theta_2 = np.pi/4
    delta_theta = theta_1 - theta_2
    ################################
    
    #Writing the system of ODES.
    f0 = w1
    f1 = w2

    f2 = (m2*l1*w1**2*np.sin(2*delta_theta) + 2*m2*l2*w2**2*np.sin(delta_theta) + 2*g*m2*np.cos(theta_2)*np.sin(delta_theta)
    + 2*g*m1*np.sin(theta_1))/(-2*l1*(m1 + m2*np.sin(delta_theta)**2))
    
    f3 = (m2*l2*w2**2*np.sin(2*delta_theta) + 2*(m1 + m2)*l1*w1**2*np.sin(delta_theta) 
    + 2*g*(m1 + m2)*np.cos(theta_1)*np.sin(delta_theta))/(2*l2*(m1 + m2*np.sin(delta_theta)**2))
    
    return np.array([f0, f1, f2, f3])


def main():
    #Specify time interval and number of domain subintervals
    t0 = 0 
    T = 100
    n = 2048
    # initial conditions
    y0 = [np.pi/4, np.pi/4, 0, 0]                  
    
    #Domain discretization
    t_n = np.linspace(t0, T) 
    y_n = [np.array(y0)]  
    
    #Step size
    h  = (T - t0)/n        
    
    while t_n[-1] < T:
        #Keep going until T is reached.
        #Store numerical solutions into y_n
        y_n.append(y_n[-1] + h * RK4(t_n[-1], y_n[-1], h, RHS))
        t_n.append(t_n[-1] + h)
    
    
    print(y_n)
 

main()
```

However, the terminal is giving me the following output:

```
[array([0.78539816, 0.78539816, 0.        , 0.        ])]
```

which probably indicates the system of equations is not being solved. Why is that? I guess that I am not appropriately passing the initial conditions also, and I just dont know how to do it properly.

I am really really struggling to make this work. Can someone help me fix the code as to appropriately integrate the system of ODES?

Thanks in advance, Lucas

Comment: In `h = (T - t0)/n` you are doing integer division. Nomatter where the actual error is, this can't be good.

Comment: I dont think this is the case. If you manually set h to any value the program still does not work. However, I am curious as to what is the proper way of doing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the passed state variable in the derivatives function, you just set the state to a constant. You should have a line like

```
theta1, theta2, w1, w2 = y
```

instead.

Comment: It was exactly what was missing!